# Unbounded set in $\ell^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H=\{(x_n) \in \ell^2 : \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_n}{n}=1\}$

I want to prove that $H$ is unbounded in $\ell^2$.

My attempt:

Define $T : \ell^2 \rightarrow K$ (where $K$ is scalar field) by $T(x_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_n}{n}$
So $T$ is bounded linear functional so $T$ is continuous and $H$ is closed because it is inverse image of $\{1\}$. But I don't know how to proceed further to prove $H$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x^{n}$ have $n$ in position $n$ and $0$ elsewhere. Then $x^{n} \in H$ and $\|x^{n}\|=n$. Hence, $H$ is unbounded.